# Jquery (2.2.0) click listener stops working after few clicks when using .on() but .click() works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 with Jquery 2.2.0, and I'm trying to use `.on()` to set a click listener to my bootstrap dropdown menu items. The link clicks register a few clicks (2-3 usually), but then they stop working.  If I use `.click()`, then the clicking continues to work without issue.

Exact steps taken:

1. Use "My item 1" menu to "Move down"; this moves it beneath "My item 2"
2. Use "My item 2" menu to "Move down"; this moves it beneath "My item 1"
3. Use "My item 1" menu to "Move down"; this fails to move

JS Fiddle demonstrating issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/e8qgqv9r/3/

```
<script>
$('#my-items').on('click', '.my-item-menu li a', function() {  // FAILS
//$(document).on('click', '.my-item-menu li a', function() {  // FAILS
//$('.my-item-menu li a').click(function() {  // WORKS
  var link = $(this);
  var item = link.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();

  if(link.hasClass('move_up')) {
    if(item.index() > 0) {
      item.parent().children().eq(item.index() - 1).insertAfter(item);
    }
  }
  else if(link.hasClass('move_down')) {
    if(item.index() < item.parent().children().length - 1) {
      item.parent().children().eq(item.index() + 1).insertBefore(item);
    }
  }
  else if(link.hasClass('tlog_remove')) {
    item.remove();
  }
  link.closest('.my-item-menu').dropdown('toggle');
  return false;
});
</script>
<div id="my-items">
  <div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <h4>My item 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button id="menu-opt-btn-1" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            options
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="my-item-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-opt-btn-1">
            <li><a href="" class="move_up">Move up</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="move_down">Move down</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="remove_item">Remove item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <h4>My item 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button id="menu-opt-btn-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            options
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="my-item-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-opt-btn-2">
            <li><a href="" class="move_up">Move up</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="move_down">Move down</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="remove_item">Remove item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I using `.on()` incorrectly, or is this a potential bug with jquery/bootstrap? (or my browser -- currently running Chrome 48.0.2564.103 (64-bit) on OS X?)

Comment: your fiddle is using `jquery 2.1.4`?

Comment: I believe it's using 2.2.0. I have it listed under External Resources anyway. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PatrickEvans -- I should clarify the exact steps I take: I use the "Move down" option on which ever item is first in the list. After doing this twice, the third time I try, the menu items no longer move. (I'll update the question with these details, too)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I could replicate the issue..

Comment: I think its an issue with the event delegation not with `jquery version` bcos its not working with any of the versions... even tried attaching to document instead of `#my-items` still issue exists..

Comment: You can just work out with `$('.my-item-menu li a').on('click',` too as can be seen from **[`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e8qgqv9r/4/)**.. Any specific reason you are attaching it to `parent`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao -- I didn't realize that. I was upgrading some code that used to use Jquery's `live()`, and so am still new to the `on()` best practices. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @GuruprasadRao -- FWIW, after re-reading your suggestion, I don't think it's what I want.  I added the `.on()` listener to `#my-items` so that new `.my-item-menu`'s added via Ajax get the listener.

Comment: I agree then.. you need to have `event-delegation` here.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, might have to do on how bootstraps `dropdown` plugin works, but you seem to be calling `dropdown('toggle')` on the wrong element. So it might be that doing a `toggle` on an element that isn't setup for dropdowns (eg isn't the `data-toggle` element) ends up having the bubbling of their events canceled in effect making it never reach your `#my-items` or `document` elements. But this is just a guess you would have to dive into their code to see for sure.

Switch

```
link.closest('.my-item-menu').dropdown('toggle');
```

to something like

```
link.closest('.dropdown').find("button").dropdown('toggle');
```

and it now works as expected

**Demo**

```js
$('#my-items').on('click', '.my-item-menu li a', function() {
//$(document).on('click', '.my-item-menu li a', function() {
//$('.my-item-menu li a').click(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  var item = link.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();

  if(link.hasClass('move_up')) {
    if(item.index() > 0) {
      item.parent().children().eq(item.index() - 1).insertAfter(item);
    }
  }
  else if(link.hasClass('move_down')) {
    if(item.index() < item.parent().children().length - 1) {
      item.parent().children().eq(item.index() + 1).insertBefore(item);
    }
  }
  else if(link.hasClass('tlog_remove')) {
    item.remove();
  }
  link.closest('.dropdown').find("button").dropdown('toggle');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-items">

  <div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <h4>My item 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button id="menu-opt-btn-1" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            options
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="my-item-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-opt-btn-1">
            <li><a href="" class="move_up">Move up</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="move_down">Move down</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="remove_item">Remove item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <h4>My item 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button id="menu-opt-btn-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            options
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="my-item-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-opt-btn-2">
            <li><a href="" class="move_up">Move up</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="move_down">Move down</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="remove_item">Remove item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great find, thank you!  Just curious, how did you discover the bug?  Just a keen eye, or did some debug tool help identify it?

Comment: Also a tip use `var item=link.closest('.well.well-sm')` instead of `var item = link.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();`